# How can I send a form value(name array) to another form?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

How can I get form data that is setup like an array?
My form for a questionlist has many inputs and they all have as name `name='p_Id[UUId of something]'` When i get the `$_POST['p_Id']` in php i get a perfect array. which looks like this.

```
array (size=2)
  '0d2af2c0ce9d2872c3d153a5021543d1' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string '4ec83937bb4146ed6b6c0fc44311be83' (length=32)
  '99de3d39e446040fee8d7033f4ebf459' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string '3e7373d3fb5145373e4b51ce915de337' (length=32)
```

So it is an array of all the questions with the uuid of the question at top. Inside this question there is an array with the uuid of the selected answer(s).

How can i get the values of 'p_Id' in Javascript and have an array much like this one?

Comment: Exactly what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: To get the same array in javascriprt

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you just want to serialize your array ?

http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php

Answer (score 1):

You can simply assign PHP array to jQuery variable with json_encode.

```
var jqueryarray = <?php echo json_encode($myvalues); ?>;
```

Now in `jqueryarray` you will have PHP array values which you can use.